# Trying to get image from Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My HTML file has the following command

```
<img src="/5/background" alt="" width="192" height="192">
```

Which I have bound to the following inside a @RestController in a Spring Boot application:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{connector}/background", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public File getConnectorBackgroundImage(@PathVariable("connector") int connector)
{
    File image = new File("folder" + connector + "/myPicture");
    return image;
}
```

I have done my debugging and I know the method is being entered, and I know the path is correct, but all that shows is the icon in the browser when there is a problem loading a picture.

What else am I missing?

Comment: You need to return a byte array back to the client. Otherwise it has no way to interpret the File object sent from java (spring).

Answer (score 1):

Spring does not know how to handle the file that way. If you return a `File`, the controller will simply show you the path to the file if you call the REST API.

The proper way to do it is to read the file as a `byte[]`. Using commons-io you could come up with something like this:

```
File image = new File("folder" + connector + "/myPicture");
FileInputStream input = null;
try {
    input = new FileInputStream(image);
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
}
```

Another thing you shouldn't forget is to provide the mimetype. To do that you tweak the `@RequestMapping` annotation a bit by providing the `produces` property:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{connector}/background", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
```

This should do the trick.

EDIT: Didn't notice the comments, you already fixed it by yourself.